# Payment can not be done due to security reason in UPI payment get way

Tags: android

```
public class PaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentStatusListener {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView statusView;
    private TextView edUpa;
    private TextView edName;
    private TempleEntity templeEntity;
    private Preferences preferences;
    private CardView cbTempleInfo;
    private String paymentType;
    private String paymentAmount;
    private Date currentTime;
    private final static String ARGUMENT_AMOUNT = "argument_amount";
    private final static String ARGUMENT_DONATION_TYPE = "argument_donation_type";

    public static Intent newInstance(Context context, String amount ,String donationType) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ARGUMENT_AMOUNT,amount);
        intent.putExtra(ARGUMENT_DONATION_TYPE,donationType);
        return intent;
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);
        preferences = new Preferences(this);
        currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        paymentType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARGUMENT_DONATION_TYPE);
        paymentAmount = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARGUMENT_AMOUNT);
        //Initialize Components
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        statusView = findViewById(R.id.textView_status);
        TextView payButton = findViewById(R.id.button_pay);
        edUpa = findViewById(R.id.edUpa);
        edName = findViewById(R.id.edName);
        cbTempleInfo = findViewById(R.id.cv_book_temple);

        TextView edAmount = findViewById(R.id.edAmount);
        if (templeEntity!=null){
            cbTempleInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            edName.setText("Tirupati");
            edUpa.setText(getString(R.string.upa_here, "XYZ"));
            edAmount.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new Validator.DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5, 2)});
            edAmount.setText(getString(R.string.amount_in_decimal, "1"+ "INR"));
        }
        payButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            initPayment(edUpa.getText().toString(), edName.getText().toString(), getString(R.string.payment_details));
        });
    }

    private void initPayment(String upa, String name, String Description) {
        //Step 1 : Create instance of IndiUpi
        final IndiUpi indiUpi = new IndiUpi.Builder()
                .with(this)
                .setPayeeVpa("1234XXXX@axl")
                .setPayeeName("ABC CDE")
                .setTransactionId(Validator.generateRandom())
                .setTransactionRefId(Validator.generateRandom())
                .setDescription(Description)
                .setAmount("1.0")
                .build();

        indiUpi.setPaymentStatusListener(this);

        indiUpi.pay("PaymentPayload Using");
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransactionCompleted(TransactionResponse transactionResponse) {
        // Transaction Completed
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransactionSuccess(TransactionResponse transactionResponse) {
        // PaymentPayload Success
        preferences.setPaymentDone(true);
        FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper(this);
        firebaseHelper.paymentInfoToDB(PaymentActivity.this,
                paymentType,
                preferences.getTempleId(),
                paymentAmount,
                preferences.getUsername(),
                preferences.getMobileNo(),
                transactionResponse.getTransactionId().toString(),
                currentTime.toString()
                );
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransactionSubmitted() {
        // PaymentPayload Pending
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pending | Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_success);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransactionFailed() {
        preferences.setPaymentDone(false);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onBackPressed();
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_failed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransactionCancelled() {
        preferences.setPaymentDone(false);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onBackPressed();
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_failed);
    }
```

This is my code when i try to do payment button then i able to see list of Upi payment app list like (phonepay,google pay and etc.) when i do payment using phone pay first time its successfully payment done  but when i do payment again then its telling due to security reason payment can not be done and when i try to do payment using google pay its tell reached max limit can any one please help me how we can use upi payment option in android to do payment.
}